# How can I make this in LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a table on database

```
Id, Name, CityId, UserId
------------------------
1,  John, 1,      null
2,  John, null,   2
3,  Jack, 1,      null
4,  John, 2,      null
```

And what i need to do here is to generate something like this:

```
Name, Cities, Users
------------------
John, 2,      1
Jack, 1,      0
```

Like: John has two columns with CityId and one with UserId, and Jack has one column with CityId and none with UserId.

I tried grouping by names first:

```
var result = GetTable().GroupBy(p => p.Name).Select(p => p.FirstOrDefault().Name);
```

But i dont know how to get the count of Cities and Users, or should i Go like this:

```
foeach(var item in result){
    GetTable().Where(p => p.Name.Equals(item) && p.CityId.HasValue).Count;
}
```

Same for the Users too

Comment: This question looks more like giving out requirements. Please also add what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Sunil just added, because i forgot to do it

Comment: `GetTable().GroupBy(x => x.Name).Select(y => new { Name = y.Key, Cities = y.Count(a => a.CityId != null), Users = y.Count(b => b.UserId != null)})`

Comment: @ErtanHasani Maybe the answer of `kaffekopp` is more readable for you :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group by name, then count the not null CityId and UserId values of each group:

```
var result = table
    .GroupBy(r => r.Name)
    .Select(grp => new
    {
        Name = grp.Key,
        Cities = grp.Count(x => x.CityId != null),
        Users = grp.Count(x => x.UserId != null)
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Each group has a key. It is better to use: `Name = grp.Key`